# Returning (not displaying) graphics from a Module

Tags: graphics3d, scoping

I want to create a Module which puts several parametric surfaces together as one object.  For example, say I want to create a module which returns a cylinder that has a top, bottom, and cylindrical "middle" whose dimensions are based on some given values.  I tried the following:

```
cyl[x0_, x1_] := Module[{r, mid, left, right, cylinder},
   mid = (x0 + x1) / 2;
   r = Sqrt[1 - mid^2];
   left = 
    ParametricPlot3D[{x0, u, v}, {u, -r, r}, {v, -Sqrt[1 - u^2], 
      Sqrt[1 - u^2]}];
   right = 
    ParametricPlot3D[{x1, u, v}, {u, -r, r}, {v, -Sqrt[1 - u^2], 
      Sqrt[1 - u^2]}];
   cylinder = 
    ParametricPlot3D[{u, r*Cos[v], r*Sin[v]}, {u, x0, x1}, {v, 0, 
      2 Pi}];
   Graphics3D[{left, cylinder, right}]
   ];
```

So, what I'm doing is making 'left' a 'cylinder' and a 'right', and I want to stick them all together.  I do not want to instantly display them, however.  I want to be able to use a Table to call this `cyl` with several different parameters and have them all displayed together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your last line.

```
cyl[x0_, x1_] := Module[{r, mid, left, right, cylinder},
  mid = (x0 + x1)/2;
  r = Sqrt[1 - mid^2];
  left =
   ParametricPlot3D[{x0, u, v}, {u, -r, r},
    {v, -Sqrt[1 - u^2], Sqrt[1 - u^2]}];
  right =
   ParametricPlot3D[{x1, u, v}, {u, -r, r},
    {v, -Sqrt[1 - u^2], Sqrt[1 - u^2]}];
  cylinder =
   ParametricPlot3D[{u, r*Cos[v], r*Sin[v]},
    {u, x0, x1}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}];
  Normal@*First /@ {left, right, cylinder}]
```

e.g.

```
Graphics3D[{cyl[0.12, 0.3], cyl[0.002, 0.5]}]
```

[image]

Comment: When I try that I get "SetDelayed::write: Tag Graphics3D in ()[x0_,x1_] is Protected." followed by an output of "$Failed".

Comment: Perhaps you included the example call in the Module?

Comment: No; I get the same error message when I copy/paste your code.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson - try running `ClearAll[cyl]` to remove old definitions before adding new definitions

Comment: @JasonB That did it, thanks!